# Typo3 Fluid (DCE) access to Cookies

Tags: cookies, typo3, fluid, tx-dce

is it possible to access `$_COOKIES` in Fluid? We have a DCE-Element where I want to check if a cookie is set. I know that there are solutions in TypoScript and conditions, but I don't know how to access global typo3-vars via DCE.

I hope it exists a solution with raw fluid code...

Comment: What is "DCE"?.

Comment: DCE is an extension to add own Content-Elements to Typo3.

The question isnt baed on DCE, it is a fluid question :)

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you should have a look at https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Once/CookieViewHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a Cookie Fluid ViewHelper.
CookieViewHelper: https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Once/CookieViewHelper.html

Comment: Careful with this. Looking at the code, I believe it will be cached when page is generated by TYPO3. So regardless of cookie set or not, the next web site visitor will receive the result of the first visitor. Correct me if I am wrong.